# Identifying People, Places, and Organizations in Japanese with NLTagger

Tags: ios, swift, pos-tagger

I am trying to use the natural language tagger for Japanese. I used this sample code:
"https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/identifying_people_places_and_organizations"
but it does not recognize names of people or organizations.
someone help me! thanks

```
let text = "中村千恵子はトヨタ株式会社の社員です。"

let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.nameType])
tagger.string = text


let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace, .joinNames]
let tags: [NLTag] = [.personalName, .placeName, .organizationName]

tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .nameType, options: options) { tag, tokenRange in
// Get *the most likely tag, and print it if it's a named entity.
    if let tag = tag, tags.contains(tag) {
        print("\(text[tokenRange]): \(tag.rawValue)")
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for posterity, you have to check the available tag schemes for a language. For example:

```
let jpSchemes = NLTagger.availableTagSchemes(for: .word, language: .japanese)
print(jpSchemes.map ({ $0.rawValue }))
```

Will produce:

```
["Language", "Script", "TokenType"]
```

Notice that `NameType` is not available.

Comment: use mecab or a jmdict index